# No data in hidden field with ReactiveFormModule and Angular 5

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

i have a form with a hidden field but his data always i receive a undefined value.

what i'm doing wrong?

here is my code of my component.

```
      <form [formGroup]="wantPackageForm" (ngSubmit)="submitWantPackageForm(wantPackageForm.value); wantPackageForm.reset()" method="post" novalidate>

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <img src="assets/imgs/ic-plus-blanco.svg" alt="">
          <div class="modal-title">
            <h5>Paquete</h5>
            <h4>PLUS</h4>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">

          <h3>
            Si estas interesado en este paquete escríbenos y pronto nos pondremos en contacto contigo.
          </h3>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" id="inputPackage" formControlName="inputPackage">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" formControlName="inputName"
                   placeholder="Nombre" required>
            <div class="alert-message-wrapper"
                 *ngIf="!wantPackageForm.controls['inputName'].valid && wantPackageForm.controls['inputName'].touched">
              <!--<p>{{ alertMessage }}</p>-->
              <p>Ingrese su nombre completo.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" formControlName="inputEmail"
                   placeholder="Correo electrónico" required>
            <div class="alert-message-wrapper"
                 *ngIf="!wantPackageForm.controls['inputEmail'].valid && wantPackageForm.controls['inputEmail'].touched">
              <p>Ingrese un correo electrónico valido.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" formControlName="inputPhone"
                   placeholder="Teléfono" required>
            <div class="alert-message-wrapper"
                 *ngIf="!wantPackageForm.controls['inputPhone'].valid && wantPackageForm.controls['inputPhone'].touched">
              <p>Este campo es obligatorio y debe de contener un número de teléfono de 10 digitos.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="inputMessage" formControlName="inputMessage"
                      placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
            <div class="alert-message-wrapper"
                 *ngIf="!wantPackageForm.controls['inputMessage'].valid && wantPackageForm.controls['inputMessage'].touched">
              <p>Este campo es obligatorio y debe contener minimo 25 caracteres en su mensaje.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn color-green border-green btn-rounded-17"
                  [disabled]="!wantPackageForm.valid">Enviar
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

This is what a I have in my Component.html, and when i send the form to my component.ts file .... the inputPackage hidden field never have a value.

Here is my code of my form.

```
  <form [formGroup]="wantPackageForm" (ngSubmit)="submitWantPackageForm(wantPackageForm.value); wantPackageForm.reset()" method="post" novalidate>

    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <img src="assets/imgs/ic-plus-blanco.svg" alt="">
      <div class="modal-title">
        <h5>Paquete</h5>
        <h4>PLUS</h4>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body">

      <h3>
        Si estas interesado en este paquete escríbenos y pronto nos pondremos en contacto contigo.
      </h3>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" id="inputPackage" formControlName="inputPackage">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" formControlName="inputName"
               placeholder="Nombre" required>
        <div class="alert-message-wrapper"
             *ngIf="!wantPackageForm.controls['inputName'].valid && wantPackageForm.controls['inputName'].touched">
          <!--<p>{{ alertMessage }}</p>-->
          <p>Ingrese su nombre completo.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" formControlName="inputEmail"
               placeholder="Correo electrónico" required>
        <div class="alert-message-wrapper"
             *ngIf="!wantPackageForm.controls['inputEmail'].valid && wantPackageForm.controls['inputEmail'].touched">
          <p>Ingrese un correo electrónico valido.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" formControlName="inputPhone"
               placeholder="Teléfono" required>
        <div class="alert-message-wrapper"
             *ngIf="!wantPackageForm.controls['inputPhone'].valid && wantPackageForm.controls['inputPhone'].touched">
          <p>Este campo es obligatorio y debe de contener un número de teléfono de 10 digitos.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="inputMessage" formControlName="inputMessage"
                  placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
        <div class="alert-message-wrapper"
             *ngIf="!wantPackageForm.controls['inputMessage'].valid && wantPackageForm.controls['inputMessage'].touched">
          <p>Este campo es obligatorio y debe contener minimo 25 caracteres en su mensaje.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Modal footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn color-green border-green btn-rounded-17"
              [disabled]="!wantPackageForm.valid">Enviar
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: are you setting any value to inputPackage field in your component? Otherwise why do you expect it to have a value when it is hidden (and the user cannot interact with it)?

Comment: You're using reactive forms, so I assume you have a form group declared in the component somewhere. Why then, do you need to have a control with that value hidden in the template? You should have access to the form value you want to hide from within the component.

Comment: If a element is disabled, you must use dataForm.getRawValue() https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue (not dataForm.value). I don't know if work with a hidden field. NOTA: Pass to submit function wantPackageForm, not wantPackageForm.value. So you can know if is valid or not or make a getRawValue

Comment: @amal .. the inputPackage value is dynamically filled from JQUERY when the user select in frontend a package ... i have a PLUS, PROFESIONAL, ESTANDAR and EMPRESARIAL packages, in frontend all working fine.   :)